# PDA for the language of words $uv$ such that $|u| \geq |v|$ and $v$ contains 1

Tags: pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

Consider the language $\{ uv : \text{$|u| \ge |v|$ and $v$ contains a 1}\}$.

I am unable to understand how to accept this language using a PDA. How to check the length condition as well as check if there's a 1 in the $v$ portion?

The question has previously been posted here but I couldn't figure out much from the answers to that.
[PDA recognising all strings with a $1$ in the second half](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/35166/122981)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I still am stuck. I am not able to solve it. You can vote to close this, that's okay. But can you help me with this question?

Comment: The first step is to link to the previous post, and to explain why you couldn’t understand any of the answers. Any new answer should be added there.

Comment: Why am I not able to see anything? I am getting notified of comments but I don't see them here.. what is happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDA recognising all strings with a $1$ in the second half](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35166/pda-recognising-all-strings-with-a-1-in-the-second-half)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pushdown automaton accepting this language proceeds as follows:

1. Push a marker $S$ to the top of the stack.
2. Push $A$ to the stack for each input symbol read.
3. At some point, nondeterministically transition to the second phase.
4. Pop $A$ from the stack for each input symbol read, marking whether you ever read $1$.
5. Fail if you encounter $S$.
6. Succeed if you successfully read the entire input, and encountered $1$ during the second phase.

It is also easy to give a context-free grammar for this language, using $\Sigma$ as a shortcut for the alphabet:
\begin{align}
&S \to \Sigma S \mid \Sigma S \Sigma \mid \Sigma T 1 \\
&T \to \Sigma T \Sigma \mid \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried to draw a pda. But it's accepting some strings that it should not. I will think about it more.

Comment: Well then, you have made some mistake. Unfortunately you cannot expect us to debug your PDA.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more question, even if it's a nondeterministic pda, no branch should accept the string 10010000, right?

Comment: The PDA should accept a string in some branch iff it is in the language.

Comment: Okay. Understood. Thank you.